# Agregar filas a un grid enlazado a base de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

tengo un grid ya enlazado a una base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el botón "Agregar" pues debe agregar una fila nueva y en principio no me dejaba ya que me salía el error `No puedes agregar lineas a un grid ya enlazado a datos mediante programación`

Se que en lugar de agregar las filas al propio grid, debo hacerlo a un datatable y eso hice, pero aun así no entiendo muy bien porqué no me funciona, al darle al botón solo me crea 2 líneas vacías y borra todas las demás filas, aquí mi código:

```
private void btn_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
        DataTable dtable = (DataTable)dgv_datos.DataSource;
        dtable.Columns.Add("ID");
        dtable.Columns.Add("NOMBRE");
        dtable.Columns.Add("DIRECCION");
        dtable.Columns.Add("CONTRASEÑA");

        DataRow fila = dtable.NewRow();
            dtable.AcceptChanges();
        fila["ID"] = txt_numero.Text = "";
        fila["NOMBRE"] = txt_nombre.Text = "";
        fila["DIRECCION"] = txt_direccion.Text = "";
        fila["CONTRASEÑA"] = txt_contraseña.Text = "";

        dtable.Rows.Add(fila);
        dgv_datos.DataSource = dtable;
       
        dgv_datos[0, 0].Value = txt_numero.Text;
        dgv_datos[1, 0].Value = txt_nombre.Text;
        dgv_datos[3, 0].Value = txt_direccion.Text;
        txt_numero.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

PD: El ID se agrega automáticamente desde la BD ya que es `IsIdentity.`

Comment: Poe si acaso cuando haces una asignacion de este tipo se ejecita de  derecha a izquierda: ``fila["ID"] = txt_numero.Text = "";``. Por lo tanto primero  limpia el contenido de tu textbox y luego lo asigna a la columna del datatable por lo que estás perdiendo el contenido que te ingresaron.

Comment: Y no entiendo que quieres hacer con esto: 
       ``dgv_datos[0, 0].Value = txt_numero.Text;``

Comment: Hola, como paso `fila["ID"] = txt_numero.Text = "";` al revés?

Comment: Parte en 2 la instrucción. fila[ID]=txt_numero.Text; y luego limpias txt_numero.text=""

Comment: El catch me da un error diciendo: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo "System.Windows.Form.BindingSource" al tipo "System.Data.DataTable". No sé si tiene que ver pero para enlazar mi base de datos al grid utilizo un datatable diferente llamado Consultar: public DataTable consultar (string cadenaSQL)